# keep getting kernel 3.19.0-28-generic must be compiled

Tags: kernel

I have this problem and I even did:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential linux-headers-generic
```

But it didn't help, any solution will be welcomed. Thank you.

---

first of all thank you for the fast answers,

- for Pilot6:
  i am runing ubuntu 14.04 and i installed vmware-player all was good 
  but when i run it i get `kernel 3.19.0-28-generic must be compiled and loaded into the runing kernel`
- for Sneetsher: I have rebooted my pc after the commands

but still i get the same massage

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is Ubuntu version?

Comment: Have you rebooted after running those commands?

Comment: Have you tried asking vmware to recompile?  This can be done with the command `sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all` .

Answer (score 0):

To install kernel 3.19 to Ubuntu 14.04 you need to run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
```

Comment: hi thanks for the tip but after that command i got :0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
so it didn't help  if there is any other sujestion's i would love to hear or read thank's

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` first. And what is the current kernel? `uname -r`?

Comment: ok i did sudo apt-get update then sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid but still same problome my kernel is 3.19.0-28-generic
and i installed VMware-Player-4.0.6-1035888.x86_64.bundle

Comment: So you have kernel 3.18.0-28 installed. So your question has been answered.

Comment: ok so i have to upgrade it to 3.20 anyway how do upgrade my kernel

Comment: There is no 3.20 kernel. You'd better ask another question and describe what is the real problem.